# How to add two database columns are show the result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

As the topic says wow to add two database columns are show the result as `ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 20`

Here i got a code which works well, it shows the result of top 20 rich players.

```
<div class="container div-table" style="padding-top:3%">
     <div class="parallax-bg" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-150"></div>
     <div class="parallax-overlay"></div>
     <div class="parallax-inner text-center">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-11 feature">

           <div class="media-object fa fa-usd"></div>
           <div class="media-body">
                 <h4 class="media-heading">Top 20 Richest Players</h4>
           </div>
     </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
                <td><h5>Rank</h5></td>
                <td><h5>Username</h5></td>
                <td><h5>Money</h5></td>
                <td><h5>Last Login</h5></td>
        </thead>
        <?php
            $query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT `user`, `money`, `LastOnlineDate` FROM `playerdata` WHERE `banned`=0 ORDER BY `money` DESC LIMIT 20");
            $query->execute();
            if($query->rowCount() == 0)
            {
                echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>No rows found</small></td></tr>";
            }
                $dollar = 0;
                while($data = $query->fetch())
                {
                    $dollar++;
                    echo "<tr><td>".$dollar."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$data['user']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$data['money']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$data['LastOnlineDate']."</td></tr>";
                }
            ?>
        </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you could see it is just showing `money` but i want to show the result adding with `Bank` column.

I have tried this code even though it is stupid

```
$query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT `user`, `money`, `Bank`, `LastOnlineDate` FROM `playerdata` WHERE `banned`=0 ORDER BY `money` + `Bank` DESC LIMIT 20");
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your attempt. Do you want show  `money + Bank` in result

Comment: Maybe just "Echo"  is missing?

Answer (score 2):

To add two columns in sql, use a plus sign.

```
select money + bank as total
, etc
order by total desc
```

Answer (score 1):

i think **CONCAT()** is what you looking for :

```
SELECT CONCAT(`money`, '', `Bank`), etc FROM `playerdata` ...
```

Comment: Why would you think that?

Comment: @DanBracuk cause he wanted to add bank column to money col. chris has to tell us about that